# Why module not found error occur in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to connect firebase data base to react app but it give error module not found

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth";
 const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: ,
    authDomain: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId: ,
    appId: 
 })
 export const auth = app.auth()
 export default app
```

This is a picture of error
[image]

Comment: import path needs to correspond with node_modules catalog. Are you sure you have that module installed? btw ain't hat @firebase/app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check if firebase exists in your package.json file dependencies

If not found you can run:

```
npm i @firebase/app
```

If found you can reinstall the package